# css/html ul table row elements distribute horizontally

Tags: html, css, html-table, html-lists

I am trying to distribute the three boxes evenly over the entire row. I tried adding "width:100%" and deleting the padding in the last child, but it doesn't seem to do the trick.

In the end, the three boxes should have the same width which is distributed over the max width of the row, which adjusts itself to the screen size.

```css
.bottom_section {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
}

.bottom_section ul {
  display: table-row;
  height: 100%;
}

.bottom_section ul li {
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 100%;
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 0 30px 20px 0;
}

.bottom_section ul li:last-child {
  padding-right: 0;
}

.bottom_section ul li div {
  padding: 25px 15px;
  height: 100%;
  background: right top no-repeat #FFF;
}

.bottom_section ul li div h3 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 35px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #FF5C1B;
  text-align: center;
}

.bottom_section ul li:first-child div h3 {
  background: center top no-repeat;
}

.bottom_section ul li:nth-child(2) div h3 {
  background: center top no-repeat;
}

.bottom_section ul li:last-child div h3 {
  background: center top no-repeat;
}

.bottom_section ul li div p {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #6e6e6e;
  line-height: 24px;
}
```

```html
<section class="bottom_section">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div style="text-align: center;">
        <i class="fa fa-car" style="font-size:60px;color:red;"></i>
        <h3>Some text</h3>
        <p>Some text</p>

      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div style="text-align: center;">
        <i class="fa fa-car" style="font-size:60px;color:red;"></i>
        <h3>Some text</h3>
        <p>Some text</p>

      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div style="text-align: center;">
        <i class="fa fa-car" style="font-size:60px;color:red;"></i>
        <h3>Some text</h3>
        <p>Some text</p>

      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

thanks in advance for any tips

EDIT: after the first few answers, it seems as if in fact, the distribution is fine. the problem is the padding, as all elements have a 30px padding right, except for the last child (0px). I added padding to left and right, and added no padding left to "first-child", but then the middle box is smaller. still trying out and looking forward to elegant solutions. thanks

Comment: EDIT: after the first few answers, it seems as if in fact, the distribution is fine. the problem is the padding, as all elements have a 30px padding right, except for the last child (0px). I added padding to left and right, and added no padding left to "first-child", but then the middle box is smaller. still trying out and looking forward to elegant solutions. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you need 1-dimensional formatting, I would recommend using [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex)

```css
.bottom_section {}

.bottom_section ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.bottom_section ul li {
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 0 30px 20px 0;
}

.bottom_section ul li:last-child {
  padding-right: 0;
}

.bottom_section ul li div {
  padding: 25px 15px;
  height: 100%;
  background: right top no-repeat #FFF;
}

.bottom_section ul li div h3 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 35px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #FF5C1B;
  text-align: center;
}

.bottom_section ul li:first-child div h3 {
  background: center top no-repeat;
}

.bottom_section ul li:nth-child(2) div h3 {
  background: center top no-repeat;
}

.bottom_section ul li:last-child div h3 {
  background: center top no-repeat;
}

.bottom_section ul li div p {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #6e6e6e;
  line-height: 24px;
}
```

```html
<section class="bottom_section">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div style="text-align: center;">
        <i class="fa fa-car" style="font-size:60px;color:red;"></i>
        <h3>Some text</h3>
        <p>Some text</p>

      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div style="text-align: center;">
        <i class="fa fa-car" style="font-size:60px;color:red;"></i>
        <h3>Some text</h3>
        <p>Some text</p>

      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div style="text-align: center;">
        <i class="fa fa-car" style="font-size:60px;color:red;"></i>
        <h3>Some text</h3>
        <p>Some text</p>

      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: thank you, similar to brahim's solution, your solution works as well, just that the actual problem is the padding, since the last child has no padding right, hence is larger than the other two. see brahim's solution with green border

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work on Chrome with width:100% on bottom_section.
(just added green border so it shows column with)
Which browser are you using ?

```css
.bottom_section {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width:100%;
}

.bottom_section ul {
  display: table-row;
  height: 100%;
}

.bottom_section ul li {
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 100%;
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 0 30px 20px 0;
  border:1px solid green;
}

.bottom_section ul li:last-child {
  padding-right: 0;
}

.bottom_section ul li div {
  padding: 25px 15px;
  height: 100%;
  background: right top no-repeat #FFF;
}

.bottom_section ul li div h3 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 35px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #FF5C1B;
  text-align: center;
}

.bottom_section ul li:first-child div h3 {
  background: center top no-repeat;
}

.bottom_section ul li:nth-child(2) div h3 {
  background: center top no-repeat;
}

.bottom_section ul li:last-child div h3 {
  background: center top no-repeat;
}

.bottom_section ul li div p {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #6e6e6e;
  line-height: 24px;
}
```

```html
<section class="bottom_section">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div style="text-align: center;">
        <i class="fa fa-car" style="font-size:60px;color:red;"></i>
        <h3>Some text</h3>
        <p>Some text</p>

      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div style="text-align: center;">
        <i class="fa fa-car" style="font-size:60px;color:red;"></i>
        <h3>Some text</h3>
        <p>Some text</p>

      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div style="text-align: center;">
        <i class="fa fa-car" style="font-size:60px;color:red;"></i>
        <h3>Some text</h3>
        <p>Some text</p>

      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: you are right, this is what i had tried before. with the green border it becomes very clear, that the problem is the padding, as the last child has no padding right, hence making it bigger.